# Does the space group P63/m (No. 176) have C6 rotation symmetry?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry, group-theory, crystals

Recently I'm working on a compound with space group P63/m. The top view of its structure is shown below (where only atoms of z=1/4 are shown).
[image: Top view of the structure]

From the list of space groups ([Wiki: List of Space Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_groups)), I found that the space group P63/m has a subgroup of $C_{6h}$, which means that the system should have $C_{6}$ rotation symmetry. However, by checking the previously mentioned structure, I cannot find such a $C_{6}$ rotation axis.

Is there anyone who can help me to find out the "missing" $C_{6}$ rotation axis? Or did I misunderstand the symmetry of this system?

Comment: Have you tried rotating the crystal around to put the $a$ or $b$ axis perpendicular to the plane of observation? Maybe one of those directions has the $C_6$ in your structure.

Comment: I didn't consider the axis along other direction because the lattice constant $c$ can be changed independently from $a$ and $b$. Thus if there exists a 6-fold rotation axis which is not along the $z$ direction, the rotation would mix the $z$-coordinate with $x$ and $y$. Such a rotation should not be preserved if we arbitrarily change the $c$ value, I think.

Comment: your logic doesn't make sense to me, axes are arbitrary. I would try looking at those other axes instead of ignoring them.

Comment: Let me put it this way: the point group is $C_{6h}$, which means there is a mirror plane perpendicular to the rotation axis. And in this system, the only presented mirror plane is the $xy$-plane, thus the corresponding 6-fold axis should be along the $z$ direction.

Comment: Which material is this? Can you link to a cif or crystallography database entry?

Comment: This material has the same structure as TlMo3Se3, you can find the it at [link](https://materials.springer.com/isp/crystallographic/docs/sd_0302235)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that space group P6$_{3}$/m does have a corresponding point group of $C_{6h}$, and it does not have the symmetry of $C_6$.

This is not contradictory because P6$_{3}$/m is a *non-symmorphic* space group. A non-symmorphic group has at least one element that contain non-interger translation.
If we put all pure translations into a group *T*, we can see that *T* is a subgroup of the space group *G*. And we can divide *G* by *T* to get a *factor group* *F*, which is a subgroup of *G*.

For a symmorphic group, the factor group *F* is nothing but its corresponding point group *P*, while for a non-symmorphic group, its point group is obtained by omitting the translation part of the factor group. In this case the point group is isomorphic to *F*, but it is not a subgroup of *G*.

Therefore, despite that $C_6$ is an element of point group $C_{6h}$, since $C_{6h}$ is not a subgroup of P6$_3$/m, $C_6$ is not an element of space group P6$_3$/m. The corresponding element in the factor group is the screw operation {$C_6$|(0,0,1/2)}.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have simple (proper) 6-fold rotation axes, but (improper) 6-fold screw axes, that is a rotation followed by a translattion along the c-axis. In your picture only atoms at z=1/4 are shown; so you're missing the translation and you cannot see the screw axis. enlarge the z- range and you will see the 6-fold symmetry; look at the TlMo3Se3 below, the 6-fold axis is evident.
[image]